# How to export watermark pdf with iTextsharp by ashx?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, watermark, ashx

I am using iTextsharp to make download watermark PDF by ashx. 
The result file is empty,no content. But the page size is correct.
How can I fix this?

```
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=pdfexample.pdf");
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length); //, memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length
            context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
```